# SQLAlchemy Expression Language problem

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, mod-python

I'm trying to convert this to something sqlalchemy expression
language compatible, I don't know if it's possible out of box and
are hoping someone more experienced can help me along. The backend
is PostgreSQL and if I can't make it as an expression I'll create
a string instead::

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT date_trunc('month', x.x) as date,
    COALESCE(b.res1, 0) AS res1,
    COALESCE(b.res2, 0) AS res2
FROM 
    generate_series(
        date_trunc('year', now() - interval '1 years'), 
        date_trunc('year', now() + interval '1 years'),
        interval '1 months'
    ) AS x
LEFT OUTER JOIN(
    SELECT
        date_trunc('month', access_datetime) AS when,
        count(NULLIF(resource_id != 1, TRUE)) AS res1,
        count(NULLIF(resource_id != 2, TRUE)) AS res2
    FROM tracking_entries
    GROUP BY 
        date_trunc('month', access_datetime)
    ) AS b
ON (date_trunc('month', x.x) = b.when)
```

First of all I got a class TrackingEntry mapped to tracking_entries,
the select statement within the outer joined can be converted to something
like (pseudocode)::

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func, select
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

stmt = select([
    func.date_trunc('month', TrackingEntry.resource_id).label('when'),
    func.count(func.nullif(TrackingEntry.resource_id != 1, True)).label('res1'),
    func.count(func.nullif(TrackingEntry.resource_id != 2, True)).label('res2')
    ],
    group_by=[func.date_trunc('month', TrackingEntry.access_datetime), ])
```

Considering the outer select statement I have no idea how to build it, my guess is
something like::

```
outer = select([
        func.distinct(func.date_trunc('month', ?)).label('date'),
        func.coalesce(?.res1, 0).label('res1'),
        func.coalesce(?.res2, 0).label('res2')
    ],
    from_obj=[
        func.generate_series(
                datetime.now(),
                datetime.now() + timedelta(days=365),
                timedelta(days=1)
            ).label(x)
    ])
```

Then I suppose I have to link those statements together without using
foreign keys::

```
outer.outerjoin(stmt???).??(func.date_trunc('month', ?.?), ?.when)
```

Anyone got any suggestions or even better a solution?

http://pastie.org/994367

Answer (score 1):

not a full answer but when you want to join select() objects together they have a ".c." attribute, they effectively gain the same interface as the Table itself.   so

```
s1 = select(...)
s2 = select(...)

s3 = select([s1,s2]).select_from(s1.join(s2, s1.c.foo==s2.c.bar))
```

The same applies for functions

```
select ([func.foo(s1.c.x)]).select_from(s1.join(s2, ...))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it now. Running postmaster in debug mode made it alot easier seeing what the resulting queries actually looked like, helped me figure out where the issues where. I also had to use .alias(somename) on one of the selects, postgresql didn't enjoy the anonymous naming.